# onClick animations works Only once in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I want to make a game in React.js simlar to this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfgyRk2QpJw

This is what I have so far:
https://door-game.netlify.com/

Here is the key code:

```
class App extends Component { 

getComponent(event) {
  event.currentTarget.style.animation = 'App-logo-spin 2s linear';
}   

render() {    
   return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

        <div className="App-logo" alt="logo" onClick=
        {this.getComponent.bind(this)}>

        <div className="little-circle one"></div>
        <div className="little-circle two"></div>
        <div className="little-circle three"></div>
        <div className="little-circle four"></div>

      </div>
```

For now onClick works only once, how can I make it work unlimited times?

Comment: The `onClick` is working more than once. Check the console. Where is your `onClick()` function?

Comment: It is not. Check the demo. getComponent is the function, is it not?

Comment: It still does not work with the 'unset, and with ' ' either.

Comment: Yeah, I ran the code, it works only from console and not from the function. You need to use a delay using settimeout. I updated the answer. You can run the code in the answer. Check it out.

Comment: I see, setTimeout is a good idea, but is there a way to put it nicely inside getComponent ? Can't just copy vanilla.js inside App.js file or can I?

Comment: You can't copy it directly. But yeah, you have the solution and the code. Fit it into your App as required. Enjoy!

Comment: Well it's done half the way, still many thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Updated the demo so you can see It working with:   
    getComponent(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style = ' ';
    void event.currentTarget.offsetWidth;
    event.currentTarget.style.animation = 'App-logo-spin 2s linear';
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you've got here is that basically the css animation relies on seeing "Hey there's been an animation flag added to an element" to know to do the animation.  As Neil, suggested removing it and re-adding it seems like it will do the job *BUT* when you set it to " " and add it again one line after the other, the process that watches for animation flags just doesn't notice that it was gone. So it continues to think that it has been there the whole time.

The situation is pretty well described at [CSS Tricks -Restarting an Animation](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

The punch line of the article is that your unclick function should look like

```
getComponent(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style = ' ';
    void event.currentTarget.offsetWidth;
    event.currentTarget.style.animation = 'App-logo-spin 2s linear';
}
```

I've tested this code best as I can from the static js and got it working, so I'm hopeful it works when it's in the App.js file.

Comment: IT WORKS! Now I can start playing around with another piece to the puzzle. Many thanks everone!

Answer (score 1):

I think Neil has provided a good solution if you want to make the rotation animation work unlimited time, here I will provide a different solution you might find it useful, and more closed to the effect in the youtube video.

Instead of using `animation`, I will use `rotateZ()` from `transform` which can achieve the same effect, and also you can **setup the rotation degree** per click.

The flow is:

1. Storing the current rotate degree in the state.
2. Use click handler to update the state.
3. Update the circle style based on the state in `render()`.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWxjEE

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think it's evan more usefull when it comes to the final effect. Will try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var appLogos = document.getElementsByClassName('App-logo');
var currentElement;

for (var i = 0, len = appLogos.length; i < len; i++) {
  appLogos[i].addEventListener('click', animate, false);
}

function animate(e) {
  currentElement = e.currentTarget;
  currentElement.style.animation = 'unset';
  setTimeout(function() {run(currentElement)}, 100);
}

function run(el) {
  el.style.animation = 'App-logo-spin 2s linear';
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.App {
  text-align: center
}

.App-logo {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer
}

.App-logo-animation: {
  -webkit-animation: App-logo-spin 2s linear;
  animation: App-logo-spin 2s linear
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative
}

.big-logo {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1
}

.big-logo,
.biggest-logo {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.biggest-logo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 0
}

.little-circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.App-title {
  font-size: 1.5em
}

.App-intro {
  font-size: large
}

.four,
.one,
.three,
.two {
  position: absolute
}

.one {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px
}

.two {
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px
}

.three {
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px
}

.four {
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px
}

.un {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px
}

.dos {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px
}

.tres {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px
}

.quatro {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px
}

.ein {
  top: 22px;
  left: 22px
}

.zwei {
  top: 22px;
  right: 22px
}

.drei {
  bottom: 22px;
  right: 22px
}

.fier {
  bottom: 22px;
  left: 22px
}

.submit {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 140px;
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%
}

@-webkit-keyframes App-logo-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=main.ea098249.css.map*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="App">
      <header class="App-header">
        <div class="App-logo" alt="logo">
          <div class="little-circle one"></div>
          <div class="little-circle two"></div>
          <div class="little-circle three"></div>
          <div class="little-circle four"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="App-logo big-logo" alt="logo">
          <div class="little-circle one un"></div>
          <div class="little-circle two dos"></div>
          <div class="little-circle three tres"></div>
          <div class="little-circle four quatro"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="App-logo biggest-logo" alt="logo">
          <div class="little-circle one ein"></div>
          <div class="little-circle two zwei"></div>
          <div class="little-circle three drei"></div>
          <div class="little-circle four fier"></div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The `onClick()` function is fired multiple times.

[image]

(Here `6` says the number of times I clicked the `li` element and the `onClick` function was fired.)

But you are setting the css animation for your division without resetting it.

Reset the the animation on every click before setting it. It should work.

Initial suggestion that only worked from the console:

```
getComponent(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.animation = 'unset';
    event.currentTarget.style.animation = 'App-logo-spin 2s linear';
}
```

This did not work because, the two statements were executed so fast that it does't actually take effect.

That's why a timeout is required as shown in the working code above.

Comment: How do I reset it?

Comment: But this is all there is really, there is no external function, only css

Comment: I did, and still nothing

Comment: I think Neil is correct, but maybe you should try `''` rather than `'unset'`

Comment: Tryed ' ', same result

Comment: Works for me, do you have both lines inside `getComponent`?

Comment: Updated the demo with sugested code : getComponent(event) {     
      event.currentTarget.style.animation = ' ';
      event.currentTarget.style.animation = 'App-logo-spin 2s linear';
  }   and there is still only one spin

Comment: Just a note that `'unset'` is not supported on IE11